# Error: Extra }, or forgotten \right in split

Tags: amsmath

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this? because i can't figure out where the missing `\right(` is.

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
Μ=&-\pi \rho \frac{c^{2}}{4} 
  \left[c\left(\frac{α}{c}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\ddot{h}+Uc\left(\frac{3}{4}-
    \frac{α}{c}\right)\dot{\alpha} +\frac{c^{2}}{4}\left(\frac{9}{8}+
     \frac{4α^{2}}{c^{2}}-\frac{4α}{c}\right)\ddot{\alpha} \\
 &-\left(\frac{4α}{c}-1\right)U C(k) \left(-\dot{h} +U\alpha +
c \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{α}{c}\right)\dot{\alpha}\right)\right] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  The `\left` `\right` pair can _not_ span across lines. You need to add a closing `\right.` on the first line and an opening `\left.` on the subsequent line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that compiles:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `left[` on the first line needed a closing `\right.` *before* the `\\`.
- An opening `\left.` was added on the second line *after* the alignment point to match the closing `right]` at the end.

### Code:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
    Μ = &-\pi \rho \frac{c^{2}}{4} 
        \left[ c
                \left(\frac{α}{c}-\frac{1}{2}\right) \ddot{h} + Uc
                \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{α}{c}\right) \dot{\alpha} + \frac{c^{2}}{4}
                \left(\frac{9}{8}+\frac{4α^{2}}{c^{2}}-\frac{4α}{c}\right) \ddot{\alpha} 
        \right.
        \\ 
        &\left.
            -\left(\frac{4α}{c}-1\right) U C(k) 
            \left(
                -\dot{h} +U\alpha +
                c \left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{α}{c}\right) \dot{\alpha}
            \right)
        \right] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a different alignment and smaller parentheses would look better;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 M = -π ρ \frac{c²}{4}
   \left[
 c\Bigl(\frac{α}{c}-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\ddot{h} Uc\Bigl(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{α}{c}\Bigr)\dot{α} + \frac{c²}{4}\Bigl(\frac{9}{8} + \frac{4α^{2}}{c²} - \frac{4α}{c}\Bigr)\ddot{α} \right.\enspace &
 \\
 \left.-\Bigl(\frac{4α}{c}-1\Bigr)U C(k) \Bigl(-\dot{h} +Uα + c \Bigl(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{α}{c}\Bigr)\dot{α}\Bigr)
 \right]&
 \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]